Is it possible to include @types/pkg in your own library, so it comes with types?
Let's say I am abstracting a library whose type comes from Definitely Typed repository (e.g. @types/pkg).
When someone installs my package, it should already come with the types. Consumer should no longer install @types/pkg in their devDependencies.
Is this even possible?

If you give your package a non-dev dependency on @types/pkg it will be installed alongside it like any other "production" dependency. Or make it a peer, they're also installed automatically from npm v7 onwards: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependencies

not only possible, but common practice. For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/pubsub has the small [ts] logo, meaning that it ships with typings included. simply emit your typings when building and then publish javascript code and typings in your bundle. In your tsconfig file, set "declaration": true (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declaration)

I appreciate you editing my content @jonrsharpe. I honestly don't understand the system of downvotes and redacting content to the point of removing some notes. Why remove the part where I asked for links to existing answers and reason for downvote? Just honestly curious, so I can take note -- which is exactly why I asked. A reminder would go a long way :)

Meta content does not belong in questions. There is already a process for identifying existing answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

@jonrsharpe Thanks. Understood the meta content. How about the duplicate link as per the guideline when someone votes to close this as duplicate?

@Hoopra, I tried it and it's breaking the build/dist files. But I think it has something to do with the nest tsconfig set-up in package that I am working on -- not mine.

@duduwe how exactly is it breaking the build?

@Hoopra, some build files are missing, but I think it's with the config of the project that I am working on. The tsconfig files are nested -- extends from another tsconfig in a proprietary package and so on. I will take a look more on it later today. But thanks for the hint. And if you can provide links to it like medium examples, that would be great.

You just need to add the following to your tsConfig file:
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "declaration": true,
}

Documentation
This will emit type declaration (.d.ts) files alongside your compiled javascript. When you publish your package with these files included, typescript typings will work out of the box.
Medium example

Yes, this is possible. If you create a TypeScript package that exports type definitions, those definitions will be directly available to users including your package as a dependency. The separate @types devDependencies are only there to support usage of JS packages in TS applications.

Great. Would you be able to direct me to samples? Just need to look for more examples. I tried some suggestion here, butI got some issues.
